# Unable to comment due to reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

Today a user asked a question that I thought I was able to ***help*** him by giving a link to another question. The problem is that I still don have enough reputation to comment someone else question, although I can answer it.

So I wrote an "answer" that would lead him to right place, and I even started it with ***[I would post this as a comment but I can't, so I'll be posting it as an answer]*** to make it crystal clear that I know that it should be a comment, but I was *unable* to post one.

Few minutes later my "answer" was deleted. Saying that my answer wasn't adequate and that if the question is a copy it should be flagged as a copy and etc. Now, the first line of my question already says that! I *know* that it should be a comment, but I can't post a comment yet.

Above everything else, **in my opinion**, this should be a website where people get help with their questions.

**My question is:** How am I supposed to "do the right thing" if I still don't have enough reputation to do so? Should I just take on the bureaucracy and don't help the user?

Also, notice that I am not asking to undelete my answer or anything similar, the user already got the link because other people posted the link -the same that I was trying to post- on the comments, so I don't really care now about that answer. I am asking it here to know how to proceed in future occurrences.

Comment: Downvoting requires 125 reputation, which also means that you are able to post a comment. Soooo.... Can someone explain the downvotes? Even the reputation here being separated from SO, it still isn't a good thing to have.

Comment: [Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement, sometimes.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) Potentially it's a reaction to "I've seen this question before... somewhere".

Comment: Downvotes on meta often mean disagreement, also noone is required to leave a comment when downvoting

Comment: `Above everything else, in my opinion, this should be a website where people get help with their questions.` Stack Overflow is not a programming help site

Comment: @Xaphanius yea this site is pretty conservative.

Comment: @santiago then what is it?

Comment: it is a site to gather questions and answers, as a repository for information. No one is obliged in any way to assist anyone else.

Answer (score 7):

What if the question you wished to direct him to had been on another site? What if it had been on someone's personal blog? What if you weren't sure the link would still work tomorrow, or next week? What would you have done then?

Given up?

Or summarized what you were linking to in a form that could've helped the asker, credited the original author, and *then* provided a link?

That's what I'd have done. And I suspect you would too.

There are [some conveniences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) that you will soon earn the privilege to access, but until then you have the infinite resources of your own experience and creativity to draw on. Why not make use of them?

Comment: I see your point, but what about flagging something as a duplicate? I am still really far from being able to do that, so how can I deal with it?

I also agree with the "infinite resources of your own experience and creativity to draw on" you said, but I tried to exercise them and that is what brought me here, haha

Comment: You're 10 points away, fwiw... But you got pretty close with your answer as-is. Next time focus more on answering and less on apologizing.